# Adding Elements of Stacked Array Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy stacked array like so:

```
[[10. 12. 15. 20. 24. 20.]
 [40. 48. 60. 20. 24. 20.]]
```

How can I add each of the elements together and create a 1D array so that it becomes:

```
[50. 60. 75. 40. 48. 40]
```

I also need this this to work no matter how many lists are in the stacked array. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array.sum(axis=0)`

```
a = np.array([[10., 12., 15., 20., 24., 20.],
              [40., 48., 60. ,20., 24., 20.]])

a.sum(axis=0)
```

Or

```
np.sum(a,axis=0)
```

Both gives

```
array([50., 60., 75., 40., 48., 40.])
```

Comment: or `np.sum(python_list, axis=0)`

Answer (score 0):

A "pure Python" solution (i.e., non-`numpy`-based), might be:

```
summed_list_1D = list(map(sum, zip(*python_list_2D)))
```